# Keep getting error when trying to map WinForms Button to new Form (Using visual studio & c++)

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build a simple program in C++ using Windows Forms. My goal is when you click a button on the main Form, it will open the 2nd Form and hide the initial one, but I'm getting a bunch of compile errors:

1. C2039:  'second_form': is not a member of 'CLRWINFORM'
2. C2065: 'second_form': undeclared identifier
3. C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'object_name_second'
4. C2065: 'object_name_second': undeclared identifier
5. C2065: 'object_name_second': undeclared identifier

I've already added all the header files correctly and my syntax error doesn't make sense in the place it's calling it. I've tried everything and I just don't understand. I'm also new to C++ so it's very possible I could be making a stupid mistake literally anywhere so it'll be easier if I just post the code. It can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EVNYGXh6dKAXLv1uchzvqQSeNR1ZlMa5?usp=sharing).
The code for the button is included here:

```
private: System::Void button1_MouseClick(System::Object^ sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^ e) {
    this->Hide();
    CLRWINFORM::second_form object_name_second;
    object_name_second.ShowDialog();
    this->Show();
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with the actual errors you are getting.

Comment: With it being in c++, it could easily be an issue with a header or how I'm connecting things. That's why I thought I'd post the entire folder but alright I'll post some of the code I used for the button that's giving me an error.

Comment: `C2039: 'second_form': is not a member of 'CLRWINFORM'` What is CLRWINFORM? Is it a class you have defined yourself? Is `CLRWINFORM::second_form` a type?

Comment: The reason why it is not a good idea to post links to code is that eventually that link will stop working and in the future anyone looking at this question will not have access to the information required to make sense of the question.

Comment: CLRWINFORM is the name of my namespace for my two files (auto generated when I named my project and made a Form). So my forms are named "form_main" and "second_form". That snippet of code is for the "form_main.h" file which has the button. My logic is hide the current form (form_main), and then I need to show the second form (called second_form)

Comment: And alright I understand. Thanks for the clarification on the links issue. I'm still new to stack overflow and a new programmer in general

Comment: Add `#include second_form.h` on top of `form_main.h`, then: `second_form^ second = gcnew second_form(); second->ShowDialog();`

Comment: Alright I’ll add that and where should I be including that second part? Will I replace that with anything in my private class for the button click?

Comment: The *second part* replaces what you have now. -- As an alternative, you could add `#include second_form.h` in `stdafx.h` (and remove it from `form_main.h`), the rest of the syntax remains the same. But, whether this is a good choice, you have to evaluate it yourself.

Comment: I've added all that but now I'm getting 2 new errors. "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MAIN" & "LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals".

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I found that you just missed the header file `#include "second_form.h"` after I tested the entire code. You just need to add `#include "second_form.h"`. Of course, there is no problem if you modify the `button1_MouseClick` code.

About the error `lnk2001`, you could delete `MAIN` in `Properties->Linker->Advanced->Entry Point` according to your setting is `x86` or `x64`, `Debug` or `Release`.

[image]